# Spring Roo : database introspect --schema vm1 / Schema vm1 does not exist 

Tags: schema, introspection, spring-roo

I'm new to Spring Roo. I would like to do reverse engineering on mssql database. (jtds is already installed)

But when I running the :

*database introspect --schema vm1*

I got this :

*Schema 'vm1' does not exist or does not have any tables. Note that the schema names of some databases are case-sensitive*

picture can tell more than thousand words, take a look at it

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/4893/image000f.png

What did I wrong ?
Thanks ahead.

[Used env: SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.6.0.RELEASE]

Comment: Spring Roo forum gave the correct answer.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=108153

Answer (score 3):

Use "--schema dbo", the db name is already in your connection URL.